# AWS tool for app error notifications

Tags: logging, amazon-web-services

Kind of a simple question, but beyond EC2/RDS I am still fairly new to AWS.

Essentially I want to get notified of 500 http errors thrown by an app running on an EC2 instance.

Ideally it would be completely independent of the application's codebase.

Can this be achieved with cloudwatch - or perhaps with cloudwatch in concert with SNS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use an AWS Elastic Load Balancer then CloudWatch can monitor the http error codes with it's own built in functions.  No extra code to add.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_MonitoringLoadBalancerWithCW.html 
 They even have one just for your use case **HTTPCode_Backend_5XX**

.

.

Otherwise You will need a way to notify cloudwatch of those 500 errors from your server.  Perhaps an apache log parser?  Then you can publish the datasets to cloudwatch.  Cloudwatch can then use SNS to notify you.

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name RequestLatency --namespace GetStarted --timestamp 2014-02-14T20:30:00Z --value 235 --unit Milliseconds
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/PublishMetrics.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also set up Cloudwatch Logs (think splunk or logstash but using cloudwatch as the server engine).  It requires installation of an agent and configuration to recognize the app logfile, but can then push to Cloudwatch, where you can set up the Cloudwatch alarms to use SNS for notifications.  If you are using IIS or Apache (or any fairly popular web server) the log file format should be recognized easily and handled by CW Logs with no problem:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/CWL_GettingStarted.html